# Import переменных из функций других файлов Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, функции, python-import

Необходимость **импорта значений переменных из функций других файлов**. Но при попытке сделать это **получаю ошибку** вида **ImportError**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import folder
  File "---path---\folder\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from main import root
ImportError: cannot import name 'root' from 'main' (---path---\main.py)
```

**Детали:** пытаюсь в **отдельном файле** писать "характеристики" обьектов и классов при создании приложения на **tkinter** чтобы не засорять основное приложение. Для этого хочу импортировать root, чтобы сделать bind от кнопки, и перенести фокус на него.

**Код файла ---path---\main.py:**

```
from tkinter import *
import folder

def set_app():
    global root, btn

    root = Tk()
    btn = Button(master=root)
    btn.pack()
    # no returns here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global btn
    set_app()
    folder.some_f(btn)
    root.mainloop()
```

**Код файла ---path---\folder\ __**init** __.py:**

```
from main import root

def some_f(obj): 
    obj.bind('<ButtonPress>', root.focus())
```

**Python 3.8.10 - 64 bit. Windows 7.**

Comment: Внутри пакета (между файлами в одном пакете) импорт нужно делать относительный как `from .main import root` или абсолютный `from folder.main import root`, но не просто по имени файла без py

Comment: @insolor у проекта немного другое расположение файлов. необходимо "выйти из папки", и перейти в другую. Это выглядит как:
tt  /n
----__pycache__/n
----folder  /n
--------__pycache__   /n
--------__init__.py  /n
----main.py /n

Comment: @insolor init лежить **в** папке, а main возле

Comment: @insolor использовал ```from ..main import root```, получил 
```ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package ```

Comment: Зачем вы делаете какую-то чехарду с глобальными переменными, если вы всё равно в main явно вызываете folder.some_f ? Просто сделайте, чтобы эта функция явно принимала не одну переменную obj, а ещё и root. А прокидывать глобальные переменные между модулями - это то ещё извращение

Comment: @GreenOwl `init лежить в папке, а main возле` - значит в `__init__` нужно с одной точкой импорт делать. Если нужно "выйти из папки" (за пределы пакета folder), то нужно абсолютный импорт импорт использовать, импорт через две точки не сработает, относительный импорт не позволяет "выйти из пакета" (о чем и говорит вам ошибка).

Comment: "у проекта немного другое расположение файлов" - укажите в самом вопросе конкретно ваше расположение файлов.